# How to set LibreOffice to record and show changes by default?

Tags: 13.10, libreoffice

I would like to modify the default behavior of LibreOffice so that it records and shows changes that I make. Can I do that?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? Any unsolved issues?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - but you need a macro to enable recording of changes by default. The following `LibreOffice Basic` code enables recording of changes (created using the macro recorder):

```vb
sub record_changes
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem define variables
dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem get access to the document
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args1(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "TrackChanges"
args1(0).Value = true

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:TrackChanges", "", 0, args1())

end sub
```

To make LibreOffice run that macro every time when a new Writer document is created, just assign that macro to the "`New Document`" event.

### EDIT:

This macros works only for LibreOffice Writer documents. To make it work with LO Calc instead, you will have to replace "**`TrackChanges`**" with "**`TraceChangeMode`**" in the macro code.